# How secure is encryption provided by CryptProtectData API?

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption

Say, if I encrypt some text using [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API without specifying the `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag. If I understood it correctly, doing so will allow only the user that my application was running under to decrypt it.

Let's assume that I saved the resulting ciphertext data in `HKCU` registry key for my application. So obviously some other users (from other user accounts) will be able to read that data from registry.

My question is, will any other user on that computer be able to decrypt it without having the initial user log in to that machine?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the remarks section: Typically, only a user with logon credentials that match those of the user who encrypted the data can decrypt the data. In addition, decryption usually can only be done on the computer where the data was encrypted. However, a user with a roaming profile can decrypt the data from another computer on the network.
If the CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE flag is set when the data is encrypted, any user on the computer where the encryption was done can decrypt the data. To answer your question: No

Comment: Without addressing specifics, if the encryption doesn't use a well-known and proven secure encrpytion algorithm and doesn't provide near-perfect security against key leakage there is no reason to think it provides any security at all.

Comment: @Asesh: If it was clear, I wouldn't be asking it. For instance, if they just used that user's session GUID for encryption, anyone can get it without the user logging in, etc. Microsoft are known for doing blunders like that in the past.

Comment: As an aside, your assumption that HKCU is exposed to other users is incorrect.  Only administrators can read other user's registry hives.  (And of course an administrator could just install a keylogger to steal the other user's passwords.)

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, no other user can decrypt it. User master key is needed to decrypt the data and it is created by user password. So copying the registry info doesn't allow to decrypt the data.

> Master Key, created and encrypted with user's password, is stored in a
>   separate file in the Master Key storage folder along with other system
>   data. User's Master Keys are stored in %APPDATA%/Microsoft/Protect/%SID%,
>   where %APPDATA% is the Application Data directory.

[More info here](https://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=28#23)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks for the link. Although I didn't know that Microsoft kept a copy of a user's password.

Comment: it is always encrypted and stored in SAM database.